# Why parent object cannot be assigned to a child reference in java?

Tags: java

The is a compile time error displayed on the console when I try to assign a parent object to a child reference. Why parent object cannot be assigned to a child reference in java?

Comment: A `Car` is a `Vehicle`. But the converse is not true

Comment: @user7 "the converse is not [always] true" :)

Comment: We need code example and need to know what the error is.

Comment: @user7, how do you know this is about inheritance and not a one-to-many relationship?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because the OP spoke about parent and child instances and what do you mean by one-to-many here?

Comment: Really? Having a parent-child, or one-to-many, relationship between objects is such a common thing. A vehicle has one or more wheels, a father can have many sons and daughters. Both are parent-child relationships , also known as one-to-many relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [user7 said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379577/why-parent-object-cannot-be-assigned-to-a-child-reference-in-java#comment85759732_49379577) and [Stultuske updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49379577/why-parent-object-cannot-be-assigned-to-a-child-reference-in-java#comment85759782_49379577), a `Car` is a `Vehicle`, but not all `Vehicles` are `Car`s. So this:

```
Vehicle v = /*...some kind of Vehicle...*/;
Car c = v;
```

...makes no sense. What if `v` doesn't refer to a `Car` instance?

More formally, it would violate the contract. Say we have:

```
class Vehicle {
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    public void drive() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Suppose this actually worked:

```
Car c = new Vehicle(); // Doesn't work, but let's pretend it does
```

What should happen if you call `c.drive()`? The contract (`Car`) says it has a `drive` method, but the object (of type `Vehicle`) does not.

Even if `Car` didn't add any (public) features, it's still misleading to have a `Car`-typed variable (which, by definition, refers to `Car` instances or instances of a `Car` subclass) refer to a `Vehicle` object. The `Vehicle` isn't (necessarily) a `Car`.

If you have a `Vehicle` reference to an object and you **know** the object is actually a `Car`, then you can cast it:

```
Vehicle v = new Car();
Car c = (Car)v;
```

...since there's no mismatch there; the object actually is a `Car`. The cast tells the compiler you, the programmer, are taking responsibility for the object that `v` refers to actually being compatible with `Car`. (And the JVM checks at runtime, so if you're wrong, you get a `ClassCastException`.)

Comment: I couldn't find a dupetarget, so added a community wiki answer instead. Beginners can easily not grasp this point.

Comment: The question is so unclear there is no way to know if this answer is relevant at all.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I don't find the question remotely unclear. In fact, given the basic nature of the question, I find it surprisingly clearly asked.

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson. I got the idea behind it.